# How do I access these array elements (browser console is saying the elements equal different values at the same time)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Heres a picture of what the browser console says when I do console.log(portfolio) where portfolio is the array. As you can see, it says the array is full of zeros but then also contains other numbers that aren't 0 in the same indices.

Picture of Array Values(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWr68.png)

If I do portfolio[i] for any i between 0 and 29, I get 0. I want to get the other number such as 1257.72 for portfolio[0]. Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
let portfolioValue = []
useEffect(() => {

        for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            portfolioValue[i] = 0;
        }

        stocks.forEach(stock => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
                const response = await fetch(`https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=${stock.ticker}&interval=1day&output=10&apikey=${key}`)
                const data = await response.json()

                for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    portfolioValue[i] += (data.values[i].close * stock.numShares)
                }
            }
    
            fetchData()
        })

        console.log(portfolioValue);

    }, [user])
```

Comment: Can you provide the data of this ```portfolio```? Add some code just in case.

Comment: ```portfolioValue[i] = 0;``` you are looping your data with name **0**. Can you add image/draft what will be the final output you want to achieve?

Comment: This is the final output I want https://imgur.com/Njf0P1d

Comment: Can you also show how the stock data looks like? eh the Num shares in particular.

Comment: Provide some data for these ```data.values.close``` and ```stock.numShares``` for easy debugging.

Comment: The code doesn't wait for the promises returned by `fetchData` to be fulfilled before trying to access `portfolio` data, so the unexpanded log shows the zeroes it was initialised with. When  the log of the array was manually expanded (some time later) the data had arrived and could be shown in the expanded item list. Use `map` instead of `forEach` and pass the promise array through `Promise.all` before using the results.